# Heroku Get IP Addresses

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, heroku, ip-address

Just starting out with Heroku and I'm trying to deploy someone elses node application on there. To start up the server I go into `node server.js` and that works. It then shows `relevant IPs { '[MY IP ADDRESS]': null }`

I deployed to Heroku, and the server is working, but it brings up `relevant IPs { dummy: null }`. I searched through the code to find what `dummy` meant. Here is what I found:

```
// find all ip addresses
// We use a dummy for a special case where node can't list network interfaces (freeBSD)

var sockets = {'dummy': null};
for (var name in interfaces) {
console.log('discovering all IPs from', name);
interfaces[name].forEach(function (ipInfo) {
  if (ipInfo.internal == false && ipInfo.family == "IPv4") {
    // this one is interesting, use it
    delete sockets['dummy'];
    sockets[ipInfo.address] = null;
  }
});
}

console.log("relevant IPs", sockets);
```

So, my question is, can Heroku find an IP address, and if yes, why is it bringing up `dummy`?

Answer (score 0):

This is misguided code.  It's trying to find the first non-loopback IP to bind explicitly to that IP for incoming traffic.

You should bind to all available addresses via the special `0.0.0.0` address for services on Heroku.  If you're providing a service behind the Heroku Router, you should be listening on the port specified in the `PORT` environment variable.

Comment: I set my port in my `server.js` file. `var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;`

Comment: How do I set it up the way you are talking about?

Comment: If you're using express, you can leave off the IP entirely:

Comment: I need the IP to find the Sonos players in the household. GitHub project here: https://github.com/jishi/node-sonos-http-api

Comment: This will not work at all from within Heroku.  If you're trying to discover devices in the local network, you need to host the code/server within the LAN.

Comment: FYI, you make the assumption that this code was for finding IPs to bind for incoming calls. It was actually for broadcasting UDP on all devices, since by default it will only broadcast on the first interface available (and it seems to be randomly chosen).